# ALM Basic Branch Plan - Purpose of Release Branch?

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, alm, branching-strategy

The Microsoft ALM Team describe the Basic Branch Plan as needing a **MAIN**, **DEV**, and **RELEASE** branch.

I am working on introducing branching/merging to a new team who currently uses source control with no branches whatsoever.

I was wondering how the RELEASE branch is actually used.

Can changes be made in the DEV branch then be merged up to the MAIN branch *without* needing a RELEASE branch?  MAIN would still be read-only.  It would basically be the RELEASE branch in essence.  The reason I say this is because we don't have that many changes but I want to isolate the stable code from new changes.  Our concept of a "release" per say is not yet well defined.  I am still working on that.

I just don't know if my team ***needs*** a RELEASE branch (considering our needs specifically).

I would appreciate some comment about the strategy of just having a **MAIN** and **DEV** branch.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the release branch(es) are used for "safekeeping".  Basically the same as a label.

Releases to production are usually a pretty important event, and you want to know exactly what source you released (in case you ever need to go back to it).  Way back when people used to create Labels to track this, but creating Release branches is better for a couple reasons:

- Labels are mutable in TFS, meaning somebody could change a label and there would be no audit trail
- Branches are also mutable of course (changes can be checked in), but this can be locked down via branch specific permissions
- Also if a change is made to a Release branch (which it never should be), at least you have an audit trail through history
- Even though a branch looks like a heavy-weight operation creating a copy of your entire code base, in reality TFS just creates a new pointer to the same files, so the storage cost is trivial

Comment: I always understand the reason **in general**, but for a team who releases code whenever they make a change with no real SDLC in place, it might be tough to pickup.  Do you think I should introduce the branches at a slower pace?  Perhaps start with MAIN / DEV and introduce the team to Agile practices via SCRUM by merging from DEV to MAIN after every sprint?  Then when they understand that I can introduce the RELEASE branch into Source Control and show the importance of a release?

Comment: Usually the release branches aren't created by typical devs, they are created as part of your release process.  No matter how frequent you release you should have a standard repeatable release process (could be manual or automated, and doesn't need to be complex), and one step of that release process should be creating the release branch.

Answer (score 2):

I went the other way when I implemented TFS at a client (replaced SVN). What I did was introduce a MAIN branch and a RELEASE branch and not a DEV branch initially as that seemed very confusing to the team. It is also hard to convey the purpose of a DEV branch to an SVN familiar team initially.

The main purpose of our RELEASE branch was to preserve a historical placeholder as said in another answer. Currently we are using Git and we have a CI server that does the release process and branches to release/$version_number. I think that concept might be easier to understand and convey to your team. i.e. automatically create release branches when you actually release.